# Recursive way of removing an item from a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have something similar to a tree structure in my javascript program and I want to remove a child from it, I used a recursive approach to traverse the tree but I am quite stuck in deleting a node from the tree.

In contrast, I will get an ID as a parameter and I should check it against the child.metadata.id and delete the child if it maches with the ID.

> Note : I have certain type of child nodes in my graph where it divides
>   it
>   path based on its type 'true' or 'false' that is if the type of the
>   child node in the metadata is if/empty.

Here is the sample tree structure.

```
 var graph =
{
    "metadata": {"id": "sms_in", "type": "api", "optionsDivId": "div_sms_in", "options": {}},
    "data": {
        "true": {
            "isEmpty1": {
                "metadata": {
                    "id": "isEmpty1",
                    "type": "empty",
                    "optionsDivId": "div_isEmpty1",
                    "options": {}
                },
                "data": {
                    "true": {
                        "sms1": {
                            "metadata": {
                                "id": "sms1",
                                "type": "api",
                                "optionsDivId": "div_sms1",
                                "options": {}
                            }, "data": {"true": {}, "false": false}
                        }
                    },
                    "false": {
                        "dbInsert1": {
                            "metadata": {
                                "id": "dbInsert1",
                                "type": "dbInsert",
                                "optionsDivId": "div_dbInsert1",
                                "options": {}
                            },
                            "data": {
                                "true": {
                                    "sms2": {
                                        "metadata": {
                                            "id": "sms2",
                                            "type": "api",
                                            "optionsDivId": "div_sms2",
                                            "options": {}
                                        }, "data": {"true": {}, "false": false}
                                    }
                                }, "false": false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, "false": false
    }
};
```

and this is my traverse function

```
var traverse = function (current) {



    if( current == 'undefined' ) return ;

    var currentChildId = current['metadata']['id'];
    var currentChildType = current['metadata']['type'];



    console.log('visiting : ', currentChildId);


    if (currentChildType == 'if' || currentChildType == 'empty') {

        for(var childKeyType in current['data']){

            for( var childKey in current['data'][childKeyType]){

                var child = current['data'][childKeyType][childKey];

                traverse(child);

            }

        }


    } else {

        for (var childKey in current['data']['true']) {

            var child = current['data']['true'][childKey];

            traverse(child);

        }

    }


};
```

Can someone help me to complete the delete function ?

```
function popChild(current, childId){
    if( current == 'undefined' ) return ;

    var currentChildId = current['metadata']['id'];
    var currentChildType = current['metadata']['type'];

    if(currentChildId == childId){
        delete current;
        return;
    }


    console.log('visiting : ', currentChildId);


    if (currentChildType == 'if' || currentChildType == 'empty') {

        for(var childKeyType in current['data']){

            for( var childKey in current['data'][childKeyType]){

                var child = current['data'][childKeyType][childKey];

                popChild(child, childId, );

            }

        }


    } else {

        for (var childKey in current['data']['true']) {

            var child = current['data']['true'][childKey];

            popChild(child, childId);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the solution for you but I'm pretty sure you are running into a JavaScript fundamental concept that when you pass an object to a function, if you reassign the Object itself in the function, the original won't be changed, but if you reassign one of the Object's properties, that will affect the original Object. So you cannot `delete current;` and expect it to reflect on the original object. Instead I would maybe try to create a recursive function that simply generates a path to the child you want to delete and then apply that string to delete the child from the top of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `JSON.stringify` as a way to iterate through your object, using the `replacer` argument:

```
function remove_ids(object, id) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object, function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'object' || typeof value.metadata !== 'object' ||
        value.metadata.id !== id) return value;
  }));
}
```

Comment: how do I call this function on my graph object?

Comment: `remove_ids(graph, 'isEmpty1')`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try not to reinvent the wheel here. We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for most of our data processing like this. It's powerful once you wrap your head around it and makes the code a lot more maintainable. Here is how you could solve your problem

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const rm = (obj, id) => objectScan(['++.metadata.id'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ value, parents, key }) => {
    if (value === id) {
      delete parents[2][key[key.length - 3]];
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(obj);

const graph = { metadata: { id: 'sms_in', type: 'api', optionsDivId: 'div_sms_in', options: {} }, data: { true: { isEmpty1: { metadata: { id: 'isEmpty1', type: 'empty', optionsDivId: 'div_isEmpty1', options: {} }, data: { true: { sms1: { metadata: { id: 'sms1', type: 'api', optionsDivId: 'div_sms1', options: {} }, data: { true: {}, false: false } } }, false: { dbInsert1: { metadata: { id: 'dbInsert1', type: 'dbInsert', optionsDivId: 'div_dbInsert1', options: {} }, data: { true: { sms2: { metadata: { id: 'sms2', type: 'api', optionsDivId: 'div_sms2', options: {} }, data: { true: {}, false: false } } }, false: false } } } } } }, false: false } };

console.log(rm(graph, 'isEmpty1'));
// => true

console.log(graph);
/* =>
  { metadata:
    { id: 'sms_in',
      type: 'api',
      optionsDivId: 'div_sms_in',
      options: {} },
   data: { true: {}, false: false } }
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Note that since the code mutates the existing structure, the delete can not work for the root node.

Answer (score 0):

Since this has been resurrected...

Vincent points out that battle-tested libraries are often the best way to solve such problems.  While I certainly must agree (and am in fact one of the principal authors of [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com)), there is another approach of maintaining one's own collection of snippets to reuse across projects.

Although I've never really considered including it in Ramda, I have handy a recursive `filter` function that makes writing this pretty simple:

```js
const filterDeep = (pred) => (obj) => 
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .fromEntries (
        Object .entries (obj) 
          .flatMap (([k, v]) => pred (v) ? [[k, filterDeep (pred) (v)]] : [])
      )
    : obj

const removeItem = (targetId, graph) => 
  filterDeep (({metadata: {id} = {}}) => id !== targetId) (graph)

const graph = {metadata: {id: "sms_in", type: "api", optionsDivId: "div_sms_in", options: {}}, data: {true: {isEmpty1: {metadata: {id: "isEmpty1", type: "empty", optionsDivId: "div_isEmpty1", options: {}}, data: {true: {sms1: {metadata: {id: "sms1", type: "api", optionsDivId: "div_sms1", options: {}}, data: {true: {}, false: !1}}}, false: {dbInsert1: {metadata: {id: "dbInsert1", type: "dbInsert", optionsDivId: "div_dbInsert1", options: {}}, data: {true: {sms2: {metadata: {id: "sms2", type: "api", optionsDivId: "div_sms2", options: {}}, data: {true: {}, false: !1}}}, false: !1}}}}}}, false: !1}}

console .log (removeItem ('dbInsert1', graph))
console .log (removeItem ('sms2', graph))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here, we write a very simple `removeItem` function, depending on our already tested `filterDeep`.  This is pretty powerful.  Functions like this are often not as hardened as those in popular libraries.  But they are written directly for our own needs, and can be designed precisely how we want them to be.

For instance, there is something odd about using `filter` with a predicate that says the opposite of what we want, though.  It might make sense to write a `rejectDeep` that would let our predicate test for a match rather than a mismatch.  It turns out to be trivial:

```js
const rejectDeep = (pred) => 
  filterDeep (x => ! (pred (x)))

const removeItem = (target, obj) => 
  rejectDeep (({metadata: {id} = {}}) => id === target) (obj)
```

Now we can then add `rejectDeep` to our personal library.

---

There is one part of `filterDeep` that might be confusing.  We use `flatMap` here as a one-pass `filter` and `map` combination.  It would be perfectly reasonable, but (possibly) slightly less efficient, to separate it into two steps:

```js
const filterDeep = (pred) => (obj) => 
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .fromEntries (
        Object .entries (obj) 
          .filter (([k, v]) => pred (v)) 
          .map (([k, v]) => [k, filterDeep (pred) (v)])
      )
    : obj
```