# How to "unwrap" a recurring nested object property?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if I'm using the term unwrap correctly here, but lets start with the test object. It has multiple layers of noise `data` that I need to either remove or consolidate to its parent. So that

```
const testObj = {
  data: {
    Name: 'Likert Scale',
    Header_Text: [
      {
        data: {
          Content_Type: 'Do you agree or disagree with the statement?',
          Text: 'Do you agree or disagree with the statement?\n',
        },
      },
    ],
    Possible_Answers: [
      {
        data: {
          Content_Type: 'Strongly Agree',
          Text: 'Strongly Agree\n\n',
        },
      },
      {
        data: {
          Content_Type: 'Strongly Disagree',
          Text: 'Strongly Disagree\n',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

should (hopefully) turn into an object that looks like

```
const desiredObj = {
  Name: 'Likert Scale',
  Header_Text: {
    Content_Type: 'Do you agree or disagree with the statement?',
    Text: 'Do you agree or disagree with the statement?\n',
  },
  Possible_Answers: [
    {
      Content_Type: 'Strongly Agree',
      Text: 'Strongly Agree\n\n',
    },
    {
      Content_Type: 'Strongly Disagree',
      Text: 'Strongly Disagree\n',
    },
  ],
};
```

The structure also needs to turn single length arrays into objects (optional). The possibility is that `data` can reappear as a wrapper at any depth, and will never be a "reserved" key that is actually useful in any way.

This was the consequence of trying to join multiple tables from a particularly obtuse api. I have a feeling this can be solved with recursion, but have mainly found lookups as examples, and I wanted a standard way to solve this.

One non-standard way I found was to perhaps convert it into a JSON string, and then manipulate the wrappers using regex. I am not sure how to do that, and would be interesting to know if that is even a sustainable solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Well it's not clear what exactly you want to do, but going from a JavaScript object structure to a JSON string to do what you want is almost certainly a terrible idea.

Comment: @Pointy I see, yeah it was sort of informed by this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/33990568/7667248 I thought it would be easier to just "flatten" things into a string so that I don't have to worry about traversal.

Comment: You may use the JavaScript rest operator `...` to spread the key-value pairs over to a new object, and then overwrite the target nested objects by specifying its new structure, but you'd have to do this for every new modification/transformation you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to clean the object.

```js
let normalize = (obj) => {
  // your reserved keyword `data`
  if (obj.data) {
    const newObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj.data).forEach((dataKey) => {
      newObj[dataKey] = normalize(obj.data[dataKey]);
    });
    return newObj;
  }

  // Array type values
  if (obj instanceof Array) {
    if (obj.length === 1) {
      return normalize(obj[0]);
    }
    return obj.map((newObj) => {
      return normalize(newObj);
    });
  }

  // nested objects
  if (obj && typeof obj === "object") {
    // iterate over each data key, we might have an object with a data object or an array with an object that contains key data
    const newObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((dataKey) => {
      newObj[dataKey] = normalize(obj[dataKey]);
    });
    return newObj;
  }

  // everything else, strings, numbers
  else {
    return obj;
  }
};
console.log(normalize({
  type: "root",
  content: {
    data: {
      Name: 'Likert Scale',
      Header_Text: [{
        data: {
          Content_Type: 'Do you agree or disagree with the statement?',
          Text: 'Do you agree or disagree with the statement?\n',
        },
      }, ],
      Possible_Answers: [{
          data: {
            Content_Type: 'Strongly Agree',
            Text: 'Strongly Agree\n\n',
          },
        },
        {
          data: {
            Content_Type: 'Strongly Disagree',
            Text: 'Strongly Disagree\n',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  }
}))
```

To convert single length arrays into objects, just add another check for the array length if block and convert it to object instead of using `.map`

Comment: awesome, thank you. Goes for both answers (@Casey Rule's too), as I took notes from both. It was simpler than I was making it out to be in my head :p

Comment: To circle back to this for posterity, your solution was causing an infinite recursion on objects that did not have the specific data key at the first level. I added both solutions + tests here https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-haze-0bi45?file=/src/undatafy.test.js

Comment: Yeah.. missed this usecase @ParthianShotgun. I've updated the answer. Thanks 

Answer (score 1):

There may be more performant solutions, but recursion is certainly the most intuitive for this problem:

```js
function unwrap(v) {
  if (typeof v === 'object') {
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
      if (v.length === 1) {
        return unwrap(v[0]);
      } else {
        return v.map(item => unwrap(item));
      }
    } else {
      if (v.data) {
        let newObj = {
          ...v,
          ...v.data
        }
        delete newObj.data;

        Object.entries(newObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          newObj[key] = unwrap(value);
        });

        return newObj;
      }
    }
  }

  return v;
}
```

Comment: Note, this solution assumes that only objects with a `data` property need to be "unwrapped", but you can move the object entry iteration outside of the `if (v.data)` block if this assumption is incorrect.